# messagebox getting looped

Tags: python-2.7, loops, messagebox, tk-toolkit

I am displaying a message box on click of option menu when data is not available and is to be acquired. But somehow whenever I change content of the option menu the message box gets looped. Like- first time it vanishes when I press ok. when I change option again second time it displays message box two times and third time three times. Can someone tell me what to change in my code?

```
#the function where I change option menu value
def module_func(event):
        #declarations

        if(dateText.get()!="" and driveText.get()!=""):
                global module_dir
                global selected_module
                modules['menu'].delete(0,END)
                select="-----Select-----"
                modules['menu'].add_command(label=select, command=tk._setit(module,select))
                for module_dir in get_immediate_subdirectories(('%s\%s\%s')%(startPath,selected_shot,selected_fec)):
                        module_dropdown.append(module_dir)
                        modules['menu'].add_command(label=module_dir, command=tk._setit(module,module_dir))


                module.trace('w',setEightText) #think problem is here


        else:
                errormsg("")

def setEightText(*args):
        #declarations
        if(os.path.exists(('%s\%s\%s\%s\%s')%(startPath,selected_shot,selected_fec,selected_module,chan))):
                #some operations

        else:
                tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error","Data at given location not available.\n Please Wait until data is acquired.")

module=tk.StringVar(labelframe1)
module.set("-----Select-----")
modules = tk.OptionMenu(labelframe1, module, module_dropdown, command=module_func)
modules.config(width=20, background="SNOW")
modules.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=5)
modules.bind('<Button-1>',module_func)
```

I think the problem is because of trace. But don't know what to add instead of that.

Comment: What type is `module`, and where is the documentation of `module.trace`?

Comment: @agold sorry i forgot to add it. I've added it now

Comment: Could it be that each time `molule_func` is called, `setEightText` is added as a new callback function? So after x times you have `setEightText` being called x times. See: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Comment: @agold yes it is the problem.. but how do i solve it? I need the message to be displayed only 1 time and after i click ok it should go. Instead it goes into a loop :(

Comment: You could have a global boolean indicating if you already have run `module.trace`, but I'm not sure if this is really what you want. I never have used tkinter.

Comment: @agold Thanks I'll try :)